# Storing client oauth2 credentials in Google App-Engine datastore

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-python-client

I'm writing an application that accesses Google APIs offline, on behalf of users who sign up. The signup process collects basic account information like, Business Name, Contact Eamil etc.. then takes the user through the OAuth2 process, eventually getting the user's OAuth2 credentials.  I would like to save all this data, Business Name, Contact Email AND OAuth2 credentials in the same datastore entity.  However, I'm getting this strange error when I try to call Model.put();

> BadValueError: Property credentials must be convertible to a Credentials instance (<oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials object at 0xb595facc>)

My Oauth Callback function is shown below. You can see I've tried using StorageByKeyName() but it gave the same error.

**Note** I'm not sure if this is important, but at the point I'm calling ua.put(), the entity hasn't been created yet.  I've seen other, very similar, code where the entity already exists when assigning the credentials property.

```
class Oauth2callback(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        user    = users.get_current_user()
        flow    = pickle.loads(memcache.get( user.user_id() ))
        if flow:
            # Store UserAccount
            credentials = flow.step2_exchange(self.request.params)
            pa = models.ParentAccount.get_account_by_token('XXXXXXXXXX')
            ua = models.UserAccount(
                key_name        = user.user_id(),
                account_email   = user.email(),
                parent_account  = pa,
                credentials     = credentials,
            )
            ua.put()

            # Try Storing Credentials Separately
            # credentials = flow.step2_exchange(self.request.params)
            # storage = StorageByKeyName(models.UserAccountCredentials, user.user_id(), 'credentials')
            # storage.put(credentials)
```

Thanks

Here's the Model Definition.

```
class UserAccount(db.Model):
    status_states       = ["IN-ACTIVE","ACTIVE", "PAUSED", "DELETED"]

    account_email       = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    contact_email       = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    business_name       = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    create_date         = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    account_settings    = db.StringProperty(required=False) # JSON config data MAX 500 characters. Change type: 'Text' for larger values and to avoid indexing.
    parent_account      = db.ReferenceProperty(ParentAccount, collection_name = "children", required=False)
    status              = db.StringProperty(required=True, default = "ACTIVE", choices=set(status_states))
    original_status     = db.StringProperty(required=True, default = "ACTIVE", choices=set(status_states))
    credentials         = CredentialsProperty(required=False)
```

Comment: Can you provide your model definitions? Also, you should be using the `OAuth2Decorator`. What documentation were you referencing?

Comment: Thanks. Just added the Model definition.   I'm not really sure which documentation this code refers to.  There's so much out there, it's hard to know which direction to follow.  I took this code from another, working, project, which I did not write.
On another note, I stumbled on Google's API Quickstart Widget for Python [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine) and the code it generated works perfectly, though it saves the credentials in its own Model.  That's fine with me, but I'm still curious why this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be an issue with serializing the credentials. I am looking in properly pickling the OAuth2Credentials object to store it.
I will update this, if I find a solution.

Update use the OAuth2Credentials.to_json() to get a serializable version of the object the from_json() one to convert it back. Security issues may arise from storing it plain text. See Flask documentation on sessions for more information in case you need a lead to start.

Comment: Agreed.  Updated with the answer I found.